# Create link to different workbook via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project where I want my code to create a link to data in a different workbook.
I have created a code that opens the folder with the relevant excel files. When the user selects the file, I want the code to create links in certain cells, and put it on the uppermost free cell in a "output" sheet.

Unfortunately I can only manage to get the code to paste the values of the cells, by using the Import code.

This is the code I have been working with:

```
Sub XX()

Dim Master As Workbook, Import As Workbook

Set Master = ThisWorkbook

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Choose file"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Ingen filer valgt"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set Import = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))

End With

i = Master.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

And then i need something instead of:

```
Import.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B8").Copy Destination:=Master.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
```

Any suggestions for how to establish the link?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your code?

Comment: Of course. I have added the code above.

Comment: Hi again. by link, do you mean a formula that refreshes the destination cell  whenever the source ""B8" of the workbook Import is changed?

Comment: Exactly! I want to replace manually writing "=" and going to the other workbook to create the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Master.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Formula = "='" & Import.Path & "\[" & Import.Name & "]Sheet2'!$B$8"
```